# How can I iterate through an arrayofobjects in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, endpoint

I'm working on a project, where I have to get data from an API.
After the data request, the response data had a structure like this:

```
  Data: [
   {s:1, d:2, f:3},
   {s:3, d:1, f:2},
   {s:2, d:3, f:1} 
];
```

My problem is, I want to iterate through each object in `Data` and display it's properties and values.

Have tried using `Object.(keys, entries)` but they only make matters worse(maybe because, I don't really understand how they work).

Comment: This is probably not the actual format of the response, and it is certainly not a JS object. Please edit your question to make it more accurate.

Comment: There are many, many questions about how to iterate over arrays and objects. Please at least do some searching and show the outcome of that research in your question. See [ask], the first section headed Search and research.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `Data` is an array (you made a mistake and used curly braces), it is an array of objects. You need to "reach inside" into each array entry and call `Object.entries` on it. `Object.entries` turns each key-pair value into a key pair tuple.

```js
const entries = Data.map(entry => Object.entries(entry))
// [
//     ['s', 1], ['d', 2], ['f', 3],
//     and so on
// ]
```

Comment: ```Data.map``` wiil return ```map``` is not a function

Comment: Are you sure your `Data` key is an array and that you're accessing it correctly? If `Data` is an object, map will not work and you need to provide us more information

Comment: Ok...will do my best to provide further information. Right now my network is poor

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the data-array to a valid JS-datastructure, I hope you mean this.
Iterate with **forEach** over the objects from your array. Get with **Object.entries** the key/value-pairs from the object and print both in second **forEach**.

```js
let data= [
   {s:1, d:2, f:3},
   {s:3, d:1, f:2},
   {s:2, d:3, f:1} 
];

data.forEach(obj => {
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key,value]) => {
    console.log('Key: ' + key + '  Value: ' + value);
  })
})
```